# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number in JSON at position 678

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

The data goes on request and receives a response of type json. But when the data is jsonparse error occurs.

Myfiles

index.php

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "php/data.php?op=logincontrol",
        method: "POST",
        success: function(result) {
            result = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
            
      });
    });
    </script>
```

data.php

```
case 'logincontrol':
      $curl = curl_init();
      $url = "http://localhost:8000/auth/logincontrol";
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json' , $authorization ));
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
      $icerik = curl_exec($curl);
      echo $icerik;
      break;
```

Result ;

```
{
  "login_status": "true",
  "login_id": 1,
  "user_data": [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "admin",
    "email": "caner.ergez@mosyo.com",
    "password": "$2y$10$QqdJ\/KjbpmdF8fHKkVYPxO7uoNsMqZ0DeoBArtP7b0F\/ZydY5Bh1O",
    "dealer_id": 1,
    "profile_picture": "\/img\/default.png",
    "user_role": 9,
    "remember_token": "nwVvpl9KqI8NfJSLQ9NgHmq0MOp0WaqeETs7kvdKMYrCSyvDgGMigSa8hiDc",
    "created_at": "2018-07-30 07:02:00",
    "updated_at": "2018-07-30 07:02:00"
  }],
  "dealer_data": [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "M\u00f6sy\u00f6 Bili\u015fim",
    "contact_name": "M\u00f6sy\u00f6 Bili\u015fim",
    "admin_user_id": 1,
    "phone": "08508884444",
    "country": "Ankara",
    "can_the_dealer_register": 1,
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null
  }],
  "title": "M\u00f6sy\u00f6 G\u00f6sterge Paneli"
}
1
```

what is the last "1" number ?

Error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number in JSON at position 678
```

The data goes on request and receives a response of type json. But when the data is jsonparse error occurs.

I have already sent a request to another page without using curl. It works.

what is the cause of this error? I'm new to jQuery writing.

*Note :* jQuery version 2.1.1

---

## Solved

error is last "1" character . I deleted this number and worked it.

Comment: the cause of the error is the 1, which should't be there. It's not part of the JSON. Check that your PHP has not got a stray `echo` or `print_r` or `var_dump` statement somewhere which you left in for debugging.

Comment: Don't write solved into the title or into the question. If you found a solution yourself, then create an answer and accept that.